# service fabric: need faster local deployment for development

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am taking step 1 on Service Fabric

I have a simple stupid SF app with 3, 4 services, I am using VS to deploy to my local 1 node cluster, one line of change anywhere in the app requires redeployment of all services in the app.  I won't see my changes running until 2 minutes later (build, package, deploy), and I have a 8core i7 with 32GB ram, I can only see this deployment taking longer with more code added to the app.

Is there a faster way to see changes in development?  can I deploy only the service I modified?  I think a lot of developers would agree with me that waiting 2 minutes to see code changes during development is not bearable.

Comment: Did you see this about differential upgrades: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-upgrade-advanced#upgrade-with-a-diff-package  it might be faster in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Change the mode of the local cluster to 1-Node (via the tray icon Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager). Make sure your Application Debug Mode (a property on your Service Fabric application project in VS) is set to Remove. This is currently the fastest you will get. We are working on a Refresh Mode (just changing binaries without redeploying services), but that will not be ready until a few months from now.

Comment: OP is already using 1 node and I would suspect "debug" mode too

Answer (score 0):

**Insane quickly way**

**1 step.** Use `Debug Mode Application` of your Service Fabric Application as `Refresh Application` like follow

> `Refresh Application` just does update your binaries changed

Right Click on your SF >>> Properties

[image]

**2 step.** Use your SF App as `Initialization Project` and press F5 like follow

Right Click on your SF >>> Define as Initialization Project

[image]

**3 step.** Be happy!!!